# What is the origin of the term/concept "pagoda function"?

Tags: terminology

In the classic book *Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays*, volume 4, 2nd edition, p. 818, Berlekamp, Conway and Guy write about the use of **pagoda functions** to study peg solitaire like games. The authors observe: pagoda functions are known to few.

A pagoda function is any real-valued function $pag$ on peg-positions that has the property that if a move replaces pegs at positions $r$ and $s$ by a peg at position $t$, then $pag(t) \le pag(s) + pag(r)$.

What is the origin of the term *pagoda*? Does it refer to those tiered towers in Asia?

Comment: The concept used e.g., to show that solitair pegs cannot esacep 5 steps into the "desert", *does* involve something reminding of the shape of a pagoda ... I suspect this was coined by Berlekamp/Conway/Guy.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of it before but a quick search revealed this. From the book, slightly abbreviated ["Computers and Games: Second International Conference, CG 2001, Hamamatsu, Japan, October 26-28, 2000 Revised Papers"](https://books.google.gr/books?id=oZHNUL0TsR0C&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=pagoda+function+berlekamp&source=bl&ots=ED9sGPaL8h&sig=ACfU3U0EHYkYLW7sqRR92R3amsIhDSAdbA&hl=el&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj2OW63KvpAhUF3qQKHcR-B4oQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=pagoda%20function%20berlekamp&f=false)

> A real valued function $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined on the set of holes is a pagoda ("pag") function if for every consecutive three holes $(x,y,z)$, the pagoda function ${pag(x), pag(y), pag(z)}$ satisfies $$pag(x)+pag(y)\ge pag(z)$$

***EDIT***

Apparently, the definition first appeared in this two-volume work by Berlekamp, Conway and Guy. ["Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_Ways_for_your_Mathematical_Plays)